# How to learn mathematical inequalities, from scratch.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

I have a lot of interests in mathematics. Over the course of 10 years, I have learnt in my opinion, a fair share of knowledges and mathematics. Just until recently I encountered several problems that look like this:

> Let $a_1, a_2, a_3,...,a_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers. Show that for all positive x,
> \begin{equation}
> (x+a_1)(x+a_2) ...(x+a_n) \leq \left(x + \frac{a_1 + a_2 +...+a_n}{n}\right)^n
> \end{equation}

I have no idea how to solve this, even after trying for a long time, try to gather resources which seems to related to this problems. I can't think of the relations between those data and books, or sources that I gathered, to the thing I am desperately need answer to, or a hint, until I open the **solution manual** which contains the solution. I was fascinated that it is so simple and can be easily understood, a beautiful, elegant solution to the problem. But I can't figure it out myself.

That is when I realized that I have no logical knowledge about how mathematical inequalities work. I have no intuition, no "mindset" to even try to investigate the right way. A lot of resources, which for example, "Secret of Inequalities" by Pham Kim Hung, eventually is too far of from what I want as a beginner friendly introduction to the field.

What I want to humbly ask is just very simple, and I think a lot of people out there also have similar question and problem like me:

- A comprehensive resource (textbook or websites, online, etc) that literally go from the total beginning. Not from arithmetic, but assumed you have the basic understanding of algebra to go further and deeper. No "slam a bunch of theorem and equation" and then hard example, but to discover the world of inequalities by heart and and by the intriguing mind of human.
- A "surplus" amount of exercises. When I started learning about calculus, eventually from calculus I to III, I already knew that math can't be learn without practice, just like anything else. You can't know how to write simply by reading other's writing ang guideline, or know how to play football without even touch the ball. This is what I think a lot of people want, and also me: A numerous, massive stockpile of questions and problems, from the simplest then gradually to the hardest.

Are there any resouces like this? Where can I find them?

Comment: This inequality is nothing else than the classic one between [geometric and arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). If I type "inequalities" "book" into google I get about a dozen hits.

Comment: @KurtG. The act of googling made things even confusing, in some cases. It makes you to have a sense of not even know what to choose and what to learn, a sense of directionless. And in some case you can't even find a guide that guide you from scratch to finish. At least that is what I had experienced.

Comment: +1 (also) : for both your question and your subsequent comment in response to the comment of Kurt G.  The difficulty that you are encountering is that it is fundamentally unsound to try to attack this type of problem, **naked**.  Instead, since this is a problem in Field Theory and/or Real Analysis, it is better to attack those two topics through Math textbooks, with each textbook offering many, many exercises for you to solve.  With this alternative approach, you are **gracefully** trained to be **fluent** in recognizing and attacking the problem that you posed.

Comment: @user2661923 That is a very good advice, thanks for it. But what about in general, the whole topic of mathematical inequalities, from algebra up to real analysis-level of things, that is what I am trying to find the most. Still, the alternative approach is practical, tbh.

Comment: Mathematical inequalities will be presumably covered by one or both of Real Analysis combined with Field Theory.  I expect that it will mostly be Real Analysis.  However, after tackling an introductory Real Analysis book, you might then have to tackle a more advanced book on Real Analysis.  These comments represent the limit of my knowledge, re your posting.

Comment: @user2661923 I see. Thanks.